# Assert that arrays of doubles are equals with precision

Tags: java, arrays, double, testng

Is there a built-in way to assert that two arrays of doubles are equal, with a given precision, using TestNG?

I currently use this method but was hoping there is a better way.

```
public static void assertArraysEquals(double[] actual, double[] expected, double delta) {
  assertEquals(actual.length, expected.length);
  for (int i = 0; i < actual.length; i++) {
    assertEquals(actual[i], expected[i], delta);
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems there is one (oddly with nearly the same names and parameters as yours) : https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master-6.11-g7bc33ff-100/javadoc/org/testng/internal/junit/ArrayAsserts.html#assertArrayEquals-double:A-double:A-double-

Comment: Good find - although it's in an "internal" package, not sure if it's part of the API and there to stay... Re. naming: I've followed the convention found throughout the API.

Comment: Well at least you may have a look at how they implemented their method : http://www.lookatsrc.com/source/org/testng/internal/junit/ArrayAsserts.java?a=org.testng:testng

Comment: @assylias That was my concern as well but it was difficult to find any source talking about whether or not those internal packages were "safe" to use. From browsing the JARs of various versions, I can see that that util class was added in v6.1 (June 2011). So it has been around for a while but I'd probably err on the side of caution and avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the assertion method is missing for that purpose. You should ask for it on http://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues

But using a 3rd party assertion lib like [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) could be a good idea too.